# INSERT INTO php mysql statement is not working due to incorrect syntax.

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Trying to figure out why the following code produces this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' , 'password' ) VALUES ('Pangamma', '39ef1e6d2fb0743000e5956362b6dc55'' at line 1

The password, email, and user are all correct. So are the database settings. I've been whacking my head on a wall for 3 hours now. Probably something stupidly simple. What am I doing wrong?

```
/** returns a reason if it fails **/
        function addUser($user,$password,$email){
            global $db_database;global $tb_logins;global $tb_info; global $tb_licenses;
            $licensekey = md5($user.$password.$email);
            $hash = md5($user.'please'.$password.'the salt');
            if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$tb_logins." WHERE username='$user'")) > 0){
                return 'error : username already in use.';
            }
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` ( 'username' , 'password' ) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tb_info (`username`,`email`,`licensekey`,`limit`) VALUES ('".$user."','".$email."','".$licensekey."','0')") or die(mysql_error());
            return 'success!';
        }
```

Comment: One thing `return 'success!';` will not echo anything. Use `echo 'success!';` or `die("success!");` or `exit("success!");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quot(`'`) is only use for values, not for selecting columns.

you can use backtik (`` ` ``) like following

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` (`username` ,`password`) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());
```

OR you can place it without anything

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` (username ,password) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());
```

And for second query you have used `limit` as a column name. Please don't use it because it is keyword of SQL. So it will give you syntax error.

Comment: This seems to be working. I'll accept your answer in three minutes (the minimum time allowed).

Comment: Now this line is giving me trouble. I applies the fix you suggested though, so the second one should be working as well. It isn't.


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` (username ,password) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit) VALUES ('Pangamma2','planetman.hack@gmail.com','e9e02ef638ddc9db6bec0dbee' at line 1

Comment: Please provide query. Is it the same as in the question?

Comment: The query is 

   mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_info` (username ,email ,licensekey ,limit) VALUES ('$user','$email','$licensekey','0')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: But you are facing error for second query. So this is not the problem. Use this for second query :  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_info` (username,email,licensekey,limit) VALUES ('$user','$email','$licensekey','0')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: That is not working for the second query. I think I can accept your first answer though.

Comment: Either you can remove `'` from limit value like use only 0.         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_info` (username,email,licensekey,limit) VALUES ('$user','$email','$licensekey',0)") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Turns out the issue was that limit was not surrounded by `back` quotes. Without the back quotes, it was taken to mean LIMIT #, as you would have at the end of a query. Since I'm still in the process of setting up the tables, I'm going to rename the column to avoid confusion in the future. Thanks for all your help, man.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use backtick around column name, not single quote.

```
INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` ( 'username' , 'password' )
```

should be

```
INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` ( `username` , `password` )
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your first mysql_query statement to this :

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$db_database'.'$tb_logins' ( username , password ) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` ( 'username' , 'password' ) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());

to

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db_database`.`$tb_logins` ( `username` , `password` ) VALUES ('$user', '$hash')") or die(mysql_error());
```